# Add a function to a dictionary using a decorator

Tags: python, class, dictionary, arguments, decorator

i want to add functions to a dictionary that is stored in a object using decorarotors.
I made a class and added a function called 'add'. The function takes a key and a function.
I want it that when i call the 'add' function, the function that i define underneath will be added to my dictionary with the given key in the decorator.

I got it working with just adding it to list, but i want to access the functions specificly with a key.

Here's my code:

```
class App:
def __init__(self):
    self.functions = {}

def add(self, key, func):
    self.functions[key] = func

app = App()

@app.add("hello")
def print_hello():
    print("hello")
```

Here's the Error:

```
@app.function("hello")
TypeError: function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

And here the working code with a list:

```
class App:
def __init__(self):
    self.functions = []

def add(self, func):
    self.functions.append(func)

def loop_functions(self):
    for f in self.functions:
        f()

app = App()

@app.add
def print_hello():
    print("hello")

app.loop_functions()
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because `def add(self, key, func):` takes one extra argument than your `add` in using list, but you only pass the argument to `key` and not the `func`.

Comment: I know why im getting this error. Normally the function that is defined underneath the decorator is passed in as first argument like in my list example. But here i want to pass in an extra argrument (key) and also the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need two arguments if you are okay with having the `key` as the actual function name, then you can use the `.__name__` to get the name of the function which will be the `key` in your `self.functions` dictionary and the `value` will be the function itself.

You can use the following:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = {}

    def add(self, func):
        self.functions[func.__name__] = func

app = App()

@app.add
def bye():
    print('Goodbye')

>>> app.functions
    # {'bye': <function __main__.bye()>}

>>> app.functions['bye']()
    # Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:
I needed to add another decorator inside:

```
def add(self, key):
    def adder(func):
        self.functions[key] = func
        return func
    return adder
```

But as another user said:
I could've access the function name with '_*name*_' and use it as a key.